# create label and put this control in href tag based on certain conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one tell me how to create a label and put it in href tag using c# code.
this is because, I need to use a single asp label control for both as label and link label.

So I want it to be programatically set based on certain parameter values. and this is ausercontro as well. Note: I cannot change the logic because this is client's requirement

regards,
Sivajih S.

Answer (score 2):

Use `asp:HyperLink` control  !

In your `aspx` ,

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="yourHyperLink" runat="server" >
</asp:HyperLink>
```

In your `cs` ,

```
if(....yourCondition...)
{
yourHyperLink.Text = "YourText";
yourHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "YourURL";
}
```

Comment: <a ID="Link" href="Link" OnClick="" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="---" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:Label>
                </a>
how can i make this programatically